# Is it possible to search and find occurrences of a word in the PostgreSQL functions in my database?

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers

I've got a query that lists the functions defined in my database:

```
SELECT
    n.nspname AS schema
    ,proname AS sproc_name
    ,proargnames AS arg_names
    ,t.typname AS return_type
    ,d.description
    ,pg_get_functiondef(p.oid) as definition
FROM pg_proc p
    LEFT JOIN pg_type t on p.prorettype = t.oid
    LEFT JOIN pg_description d on p.oid = d.objoid
    LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n on n.oid = p.pronamespace
WHERE n.nspname != 'pg_catalog'
```

It works great and column `definition` returns the whole text of the functions, but if I try to add a `pg_get_functiondef(p.oid) ILIKE '%contact%'` to search for definitions containing the word "contact":

```
SELECT n.nspname AS schema
      ,proname AS sproc_name
      ,proargnames AS arg_names
      ,t.typname AS return_type
      ,d.description
      ,pg_get_functiondef(p.oid) as definition
FROM pg_proc p
    LEFT JOIN pg_type t on p.prorettype = t.oid
    LEFT JOIN pg_description d on p.oid = d.objoid
    LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n on n.oid = p.pronamespace
WHERE n.nspname != 'pg_catalog'
    AND pg_get_functiondef(p.oid) ILIKE '%contact%'
```

the database returns:

```
SQL Error [42809]: ERROR: "array_agg" is an aggregate function
```

I also tried wrapping this query in parenthesis to see if I could use `ILIKE` in column `definition` with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `pg_get_functiondef` cannot be used to get the definition of aggregate functions. If you look at the syntax of `CREATE AGGREGATE`, you will see that that is quite a different beast.

The query happens to work without the additional `WHERE` condition because there happens to be no aggregate function outside `pg_catalog` in the database.
With the condition, `pg_get_functiondef` also happens to get called on functions in `pg_catalog`.

Try explicitly excluding aggregates, although I am not sure in what order the optimizer will evaluate the conditions:

```
SELECT "schema",
       sproc_name,
       arg_names,
       return_type,
       pg_get_functiondef(oid) AS definition
FROM (SELECT n.nspname AS schema,
             proname AS sproc_name,
             proargnames AS arg_names,
             t.typname AS return_type,
             d.description,
             p.oid
      FROM pg_proc p
         LEFT JOIN pg_type t on p.prorettype = t.oid
         LEFT JOIN pg_description d on p.oid = d.objoid
         LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n on n.oid = p.pronamespace
      WHERE n.nspname != 'pg_catalog'
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_aggregate AS a
                        WHERE a.aggfnoid = p.oid)
      OFFSET 0) AS q
WHERE pg_get_functiondef(oid) ILIKE '%contact%';
```

Comment: You mean for me to write the original query inside a `WITH` statement and then use `WHERE definition ILIKE '%contact%'`? That gives me the same error as before.

Comment: Yes, but use the `MATERIALIZED` keyword. I have added another suggestion to my answer.

Comment: Okay, I tried your query excluding aggregates but it was returning the same error. What ended up working was to `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW func AS ( /*my query*/ )` and then just `SELECT * FROM func WHERE definition ILIKE '%update%'`. If you update your answer with this query I'll accept it.

Comment: I have found a better way, using the old `OFFSET 0` trick as an optimizer fence.

Comment: Alright, I just accepted your answer and upvoted it.